# python selenium: how to use a proxy with login and password

Tags: python, selenium, proxy

I am trying to use a proxy with Selenium. This proxy needs a login and a password. It is usually given in this format: http://user:password@IP_ADDRESS:port
I am using chrome and this is my current code:

```py
    if config.proxy:
        chrome_options.add_argument("--proxy-server=%s" % config.proxy)
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work. I was suggested to use a chrome extension. I am using linux. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution found on https://botproxy.net/docs/how-to/setting-chromedriver-proxy-auth-with-selenium-using-python/
here is the version I use in case the website no longer exists:

```py
import os
import zipfile

from selenium import webdriver


manifest_json = """
{
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "Chrome Proxy",
    "permissions": [
        "proxy",
        "tabs",
        "unlimitedStorage",
        "storage",
        "<all_urls>",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking"
    ],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "minimum_chrome_version":"22.0.0"
}
"""

def get_background_js(proxy_user, proxy_pass, proxy_host, proxy_port):
    return """var config = {
        mode: "fixed_servers",
        rules: {
        singleProxy: {
            scheme: "http",
            host: "%s",
            port: parseInt(%s)
        },
        bypassList: ["localhost"]
        }
    };

chrome.proxy.settings.set({value: config, scope: "regular"}, function() {});

function callbackFn(details) {
    return {
        authCredentials: {
            username: "%s",
            password: "%s"
        }
    };
}

chrome.webRequest.onAuthRequired.addListener(
            callbackFn,
            {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
            ['blocking']
);
""" % (proxy_host, proxy_port, proxy_user, proxy_pass)


def get_chromedriver(proxy=False, user_agent=None):
    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    if proxy:
        pluginfile = 'proxy_auth_plugin.zip'

        with zipfile.ZipFile(pluginfile, 'w') as zp:
            zp.writestr("manifest.json", manifest_json)
            zp.writestr("background.js", get_background_js(*proxy.split(":")))
        chrome_options.add_extension(pluginfile)
    if user_agent:
        chrome_options.add_argument('--user-agent=%s' % user_agent)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(
        chrome_options=chrome_options)
    return driver
```

Just provide a proxy with format `user:password:IP_ADDRESS:port`.